# A few issues with iAds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

i was implemented the iAds banner at the bottom of the screen, and i have a few things i couldn't figure out.

1.Apple says that sometimes,you have to get a fail delegate, in order for you to experience with cases where ads are invalid, but i keep getting the ads ok -forever. Why is that? do i have to shout down the internet in order to get the cases for invalid ad ?

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"HAS BANNER"); //always happens

    if (!bannerIsVisible)
    {
         if (adBanner.superview == nil)
            [self.view addSubview:adBanner];


        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad"); //never !
```

2.I couldn't find in iTunes connect where you turn it "on" before release ?

3.Is it allowed to put iAd banner above a `UIWebView` ? their guidelines never mentioned that.

4. My add is always open in landscape mode, but my iPad app is portrait only, why is that ?

Comment: I solve number 1 , by putting it on the device, on simulator it always successful . i left with number 2+3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. There is nothing to turn on in iTunesConnect. It will automatically detect it has iAd configured. You only have to agree to the 'iAd App Network' contract under 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking' section in iTunesConnect. May be sometimes, the app might not get any ads for couple of days after it is released in the App store. i started getting ads in my ap after 4 days.
3. Yes you can definitely put iAd banner with a UIWebView. I don't see any special reason why not and I have done it before. [Here](http://hawkinbj.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/implement-iad-banner-ads-without-covering-uiwebview-in-phonegap/) is a tutorial. I believe you can even add the banner in the UIWebView's scroll view if you want it to scroll with the web view.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why not is because you actually put your own advertising inside other people's content, specially if you scroll it with the web view ..

Comment: I see what you mean..it makes sense when you put it like that.. but I think you are not putting the ad in their 'website' per se. This could be analogous to for example embedding a video from youtube into your website, that has ads. Youtube has nothing to loose.